# Selecting duplicate values in DataTable with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable (DT), and I have to select duplicate values in a specified column with multiple conditions on other columns, and get the row's Id.
Unfortunatelly I'm a very beginner in this.

My DataTable contains this columns:

```
Id, PartNo, Group
```

I found this code below, and this works if I would like to get multiple values in a column, but I can't expand it.

```
Dim duplicates = From row In DT.AsEnumerable() _
    .GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("PartNo")) _
    .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1) _
    .Select(Function(g) g.Key)

For Each dup In duplicates
    Debug.Print(dup)
Next
```

So I would like to

```
- get the "Id" values on those rows
- where ["Group"] LIKE "Assembly" OR ["Group"] LIKE "Part" 
 AND
- "PartNo" value can found more than once
```

Example:
In this table I would like to get "Id" values: 1, 3, 5, 6, 8

```
+----+--------+----------+
| Id | PartNo |  Group   |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |   1111 | Assembly |
|  2 |   1111 | Common   |
|  3 |   2222 | Part     |
|  4 |   2222 | Common   |
|  5 |   2222 | Part     |
|  6 |   1111 | Part     |
|  7 |   3333 | Assembly |
|  8 |   2222 | Assembly |
+----+--------+----------+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add another .Where clause before you do the grouping to select multiple part numbers, then .SelectMany to flatten the groups into a list of integers:

```
Dim duplicates = From row In DT.AsEnumerable() _
.Where(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("Group") = "Part" OrElse i.Field(Of String)("Group") = "Assembly") _
.GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("PartNo")) _
.Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1) _
.SelectMany(Function(g) g.Select(Function(c) c.Field(Of Integer)("Id")))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.. in the last row there is some error with "Select(c >= c." 
VB marked this with red underline

Comment: Works good! :) You got the point :)

Btw I missed something :D
If there is another column "Path".
And the change is that, if "PartNo" value can found more than once where "Path" is different :D
Can you help me with this too?